XPDF analysis using GudrunX: Can I run Gudrun without the GUI?
I have no idea where to post about this topic and this forum is the closest match I could find...
I have recently found out how to partially automate XPDF analysis using GudrunX. You can dynamically create an input file using a template in which you replace a bunch of parameters using python and then run the whole thing by executing a .bat file. My problem with this is: As far as I can tell I can only use this to launch the GUI application and then do additional refinement by hand inside the program. To actually execute the analysis you need to press the "Run" button inside the app. I would prefer it to just run Gudrun for my input file silently and then plot the output files myself using python. I also have ideas on how to perform an automatic optimization of the analysis parameters, but that is for the future and will likely be very difficult.
All I need to know right now is: How do I run Gudrun from the command line without opening the GUI? Something like:
C:\Program Files\Gudrun_Folder\Gudrun.exe MyInputFile.txt -s
And then out come the files the Gudrun execution creates. Is this possible?

I think this is a bit more suitable for Matter Modelling SE, you might want to have a look there

Did you try using the two Fortran executables, corrsx_in_out.exe and tophatsub.exe, directly?

I ran them but they either don't do that or I don't know how to use them properly...
